# TimeStamp to Actual Date and time Converion Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a Unix timestamp in one of the column and trying to convert actual date and time.

I tried:

```
df1.index = pd.to_datetime(df1['column_name'])
```

But, it gives the value as `1970-01-01 00:27:17.087400` when the actual time is is `16-11-2021`

Some sample timestamps are: 1637087400000, 1637089200000, 1637100000000 [Dtype int64]

Answer (score 1):

[`pandas.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) defaults to units of nanoseconds, but your values appear to be in units of milliseconds since the Unix epoch start. Specify `unit='ms'`:

```
# Your three example values
dt = [1637087400000, 1637089200000, 1637100000000]

pd.to_datetime(dt, unit='ms')

# Result:
DatetimeIndex(['2021-11-16 18:30:00', 
               '2021-11-16 19:00:00',
               '2021-11-16 22:00:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```